# GPU Fan Weirdness

Tags: windows, nvidia-graphics-card, fan, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-rtx

I'm experiencing an odd issue with the fans on the GPU that I recently bought from overclockers.co.uk. Under load, the commanded GPU fan duty cycle does not change, but the fan RPM frequently and audibly dips/stalls. I managed to record the behaviour using Furmark, RTSS, OBS and a mic.

I tried setting the GPU fan duty to fixed values (e.g. 60%, 80%. 100%) using Palit's control software, but the behaviour persists. I'm baffled, any suggestions gratefully received.

[Youtube video of behaviour](https://youtu.be/_hM6KoDZLzM)

My system specs are: https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/list/Hg7T27

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 3.6 GHz 6-Core
- CPU Cooler: ARCTIC Liquid Freezer II 280mm AIO
- CPU Radiator Fans: 4x ARCTIC P14 PWM 140 mm, push-pull, intake front
- Motherboard: MSI MPG X570 GAMING PLUS ATX AM4
- Memory: Corsair Vengeance LPX 32 GB (2 x 16 GB) DDR4-3200 CL16
- Storage: Crucial P1 1 TB M.2-2280 NVME
- Video Card: Palit GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER 8 GB GamingPro
- Case: be quiet! Pure Base 500 ATX Mid Tower
- Case Fans: 3x ARCTIC P14 PWM 140 mm, exhaust top and rear
- Power Supply: Corsair RMx 650 W 80+ Gold Certified Fully Modular ATX
- Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

Comment: In the video, I see the fan speed is keeping 58% constantly, can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: That's the fan duty that Palit's default fan curve is resulting in. Here's another video in which I've pinned the fan speed to 100%, and the problem persists:
https://youtu.be/6W-RD07TupI

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps contacing overclockers.co.uk should be your first port of call whilst the card is still under warranty.
It could be an issue with the fan or the graphics card.

Also worthy of note, but unrelated, is the note at the bottom of the PCPartpicker screen regarding your PSU/Motherboard choice.

"Note:The MSI MPG X570 GAMING PLUS ATX AM4 Motherboard has an additional 4-pin ATX power connector but the Corsair RMx 650 W 80+ Gold Certified Fully Modular ATX Power Supply does not. This connector is used to supply additional 12V current to the motherboard. While the system will likely still run without it, higher current demands such as extreme overclocking or large video card current draws may require it."

Comment: I have contacted them and Palit in parallel, but didn't want to return the card if someone more knowledgeable than me knew of a solution. I was under the impression that the 4pin wasn't necessary, I'll do some more research.

Comment: I checked again on the 4-pin ATX power (CPU_PWR2) requirement, and apparently it's only required if you're doing extreme overclocking (i.e. high CPU currents).